# "Unused argument (replace = FALSE)" error with sample() in R (on AWS)

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am running R code on an Elastic MapReduce cluster on AWS, involving data imported from an S3 bucket. I'm testing some functionalities of Apache Spark using the SparkR library. Here's the code I'm trying to run.

```
mnist_train <- SparkR::read.df("s3a://spark-rstudio-test-new/mnist_train.csv", 
                  header = "false", source = "csv", 
                  inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "")
subsamplesize <- 30000
subsample <- sample(nrow(mnist_train), subsamplesize, replace = FALSE)
```

This returns the following error:

"Error in sample(nrow(mnist_train), subsamplesize, replace = F) : 
  unused argument (replace = F)"

The same piece of code works on my local RStudio. What's going on here? I'd be very grateful for any direction.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like SparkR implementation, which has incompatible signature, shades the one from `base`. Using fully qualified name should do the trick:

```
base::sample(nrow(mnist_train), subsamplesize, replace = FALSE)
```